# I tried to make a custom lock guard for mutexes in C++. It compiled fine. But I'm getting run time error. Can anyone help me with it?

Tags: c++11

Below is the template section of the custom lock.

```
template <typename T>
class custom_lock
{

};

template<>
class custom_lock<std::mutex>
{
public:
    custom_lock(std::mutex* m) : mu(m) {}
    ~custom_lock()
    {
        std::cout << "m unlock" << std::endl;
        mu->unlock();
    }

private:
    std::mutex* mu;
};
```

Below is the code i used to test the custom lock.

```
std::mutex m;

void printOdd(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        custom_lock<std::mutex> lg(&m);
        if (i % 2 != 0)
            std::cout << i << "from printOdd" << std::endl;
    }
}

void printEven(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        custom_lock<std::mutex> lg(&m);
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            std::cout << i << "from printEven" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(printOdd, 10);
    std::thread t2(printEven, 10);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    std::cin.get();
}
```

When i run this code, it print out the following content and breaks.
m unlock0
from printEven
f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\stdcpp\thr\mutex.c(173): unlock of unowned mutexm unlock

f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\stdcpp\thr\mutex.c(173): unlock of unowned mutex

Answer (score 1):

According to reference about *mutex::unlock*

> The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution, otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

you must call `lock` before calling `unlock`, so in your ctor of `custom_lock` call `lock` method

```
custom_lock(std::mutex* m) : mu(m) {
   mu->lock(); // wait until other thread releases this mutex
}
```